# Updating documents in MongoDb collection without an exact full match of the query filters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mern

I'm trying to update documents in a collection, and as per mongodb syntax, for some update function, I do this:

```js
Collection.updateMany(
    {
        filter1: 'filter1-val',
        filter2: 'filter2-val',
        filter3: 'filter3-val'
                    
    },
    { $set: { filed: 'value' } }
)
```

and mongodb performs the given update operation on documents that match the query. However, it only updates documents that match every single filter in the query. My question, and what I'm wondering is there a way to perform the update on documents, as long as they match at least one of the filters in the query, and not every single one? So basically, a form of relaxed match, so that as long as a document meets one of the filters, then it should be updated.

Thanks in advance; any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) and [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) in your search criteria.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $or: [
      {
        $eq: [
          "$filter1",
          "filter1-val"
        ]
      },
      {
        $eq: [
          "$filter2",
          "filter2-val"
        ]
      },
      {
        $eq: [
          "$filter3",
          "filter3-val"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Here is a [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4VAQC5I1TsL) for your reference.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. Very helpful including the sandbox; now I can implement this quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$or` operator.

```js
Collection.updateMany(
  {
    $or: [
      { filter1: 'filter1-val' },
      { filter2: 'filter2-val' },
      { filter3: 'filter3-val' }
    ]
  },
  { $set: { filed: 'value' } }
);
```